# Core Data Model

Tags: core-data, entity, nsmanagedobject

I am having some trouble finding the best way to set up my Core Data Model... Let me explain my current situation...

I have four entities

1)Game
2)Team
3)Player
4)PlayerStats

Each **Team** holds **Players**, and the teams play **Games**.

**PlayerStats** include things such as pointsScored,minutesPlayed,etc just basically stats that are related to things directly in a certain game.

I need to figure out where/when to insert the PlayerStats Entity in the ManagedObjectContext. Obviously each **PlayerStats** entity has to hold a reference back to the **Player** entity it came from.

The database needs to be set up such that I can go back and look at a Team then look at its players,then look at the players games it has participated in, then see that players stats for that specific game...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I followed that whole discussion, but I certainly got enough to offer you this advice as an answer.

Do not think of your Core Data model independently.  Core Data provides complete object graph management, which includes persistence.

If I were you, I'd sit down with my design, and design the objects, their relationships, and the whole thing **without even thinking about core data or a database**.  First settle on a proper design for all your objects, data, interactions, API, etc., etc.

Then, when you have your design, you should be able to immediately determine your entities, relationships, and attributes.  Basically, if your core data model does not just obviously fall out of your design, then your design is probably lacking.  Go back and iterate on your design.

You should be able to pretty much complete your entire design without even considering Core Data as much more than an implementation detail.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I have updated my question please take a look to see if it makes more sense, I have drawn some things out and that is what I came up with. Please let me know the best way to achieve the solution to my problem.